# What is the output of the following code and is there any significance to Symbol tables?

Tags: perl, perl-module

What will be the output of the following program and Why?
is there any significance to symbol table w.r.t to the result?

```
package Test;

sub func {
  print "First instance\n";
}

sub func {
  print "Second instance\n";
}
1;
#! /usr/bin/perl
# File: script.pl

use Test;
Test::func();
```

Comment: Feel free to remove the _homework_ tag if it's really wrong. However "what is the output of X" is always suspicious as you should be able to find that out yourself.

Comment: @Snake , @musiKK : Could you explain about symbol table if you dont know the answer for the question....

Comment: can't you just paste it into codepad.org or ideone.com and find out for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Second instance\n"

A package/global variable will have an entry in the symbol table, you can try this to verify:

```
use Test;
Test::func();

for my $entry ( keys %Test:: )
{
    print "$entry\n";
}
```

Link to reference: http://www252.pair.com/comdog/mastering_perl/Chapters/08.symbol_tables.html